# AngularJS and Laravel 4 : forecast for developers (latitude and longitude)

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel-4, latitude-longitude, weather

From my tables festivals, addresses, locations I'm making JSON:

```
$festival = Festival::with('address.location')->get();

return Response::json(array('festivals' => $festival))->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
```

I'm loading the JSON with angularJS and when I type this in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="festival in festivals">
    <p>{{festival.address.location.location_latitude}}</p>
    <p>{{festival.address.location.location_longitude}}</p>
</div>
```

I'm getting the latitude and longitude.

I'm using this angular-weather-forecast directive from sotospez:

https://github.com/sotospez/angular-weather-forecast

So I can type for instance this in my weather view:

```
<weather location="36.453153,28.2092523" color="#f2f2f2" apikey="yourapikey"></weather>
```

My question now is how can I get the latitude and longitude of my json inside that location attribute?

This doesn't work:

```
location="{{festival.address.location.location_latitude}},{{festival.address.lo‌​cation.location_longitude}}
```

**UPDATE**

This error I'm getting in the console:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 19-19 [‌] in expression [festival.address.lo‌​cation.location_longitude].
```

[http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%2…80%8C%5D&p2=festival.address.lo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcation.location_longitude](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%252%E2%80%A680%8C%5D&p2=festival.address.lo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcation.location_longitude)

There was something wrong with `{{festival.address.lo‌​cation.location_longitude}}`

Now I get the error:

```
GET https://api.forecast.io/forecast/182c80b516693d7731697710f7e1a807/%7Bfestival.address.location.location_latitude%7D%7D,?callback=angular.callbacks._5 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: `location="{{festival.address.location.location_latitude}},{{festival.address.location.location_longitude}}"` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

That directive is reading the location attribute in the linking function, you can see here  https://github.com/sotospez/angular-weather-forecast/blob/master/js/weather.js#L108  That means that it reads the value once and if the data isn't available yet your totally out of luck because its already made its http request with no data.

You need to add that element to the DOM after the data is ready, I'm guessing your making an ajax request somewhere to load the data so append that weather element at that time